# Hawtio user management: invalidate session

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, roles, user-management, hawtio

We are running a hawt.io application on WildFly. We need user management on that and tried integrating Spring Boot Security directed to my custom login page instead of hawt.io's. The latter works fine but when I click hawtio logout it does not invalidate the session (which is obvious because I was not able to integrate authentication fully).

So I am looking for an approach to integrate hawt.io and Spring Security properly or any other authentication framework which can provide user management with hawt.io (including user roles).

Comment: Integration with Spring Security is not tested enough for Hawtio, so it's quite possible that it doesn't work well. I would file this issue with a reproducer at https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues

Comment: can you recommend any other java authentication and authorization framework which will serve purpose with Hawtio ?

Comment: Apache Karaf is an application container fully integrated with Hawtio, but probably it's not an option for you. If allowed you may look for Keycloak integration https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/master/examples/keycloak-integration/README.md

Comment: The standard WildFly JAAS should also work with Hawtio. In this regard, WildFly Camel https://wildfly-extras.github.io/wildfly-camel/ automatically installs Hawtio for you so it's good idea to see how it installs Hawtio and configure it with the JAAS realm.

Comment: Note that Hawtio RBAC only works on Karaf at this moment. On other application servers, it should be either all or nothing.